# Using the 'Common Expression Language', how do I count/query elements in a collection

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to use the Bot Samples [Common Expression Languag](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/common-expression-language/prebuilt-functions.md) count and query the elements from a JSON response.

I am using the expression language in the [Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer) in a standard response after using a GET to fetch the JSON response as in the [Weather example tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial/tutorial-get-weather#add-an-http-request).

Example of my JSON response:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "number": "item 1"
        },
        {
            "number": "item 2"
        },
        {
            "number": "item 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of contents used in the *Send a resonse* task that do NOT work:
- How do I count the elements in the result object?

```
- @{count(dialog.result.result)}
```

- How do I access the property of one of the elements?

```
- @{dialog.result.result[0].number}
```

Some examples for these kind of actions would be highly appriciated.

[image: Main Flow]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you mean how would you count `result` as it has `3` object am I right?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, the results of my JSON response were not as in my example. I introduced an issue myself and did not notice that is was changed. So, my examples, the count etc actually works fine.

Comment: This should be a comment rather an answer or if already your problem resolved you could remove the question.